# mremap() to \0-terminate a string

Tags: c, mmap

I'm using `mmap()`ed memory in one of my programs. One problem is that `mmap()`ed memory is not `\0`-terminated when it is a multiple of the pagesize. So in order to make sure that it is `\0`-terminated I thought about using the Linux specific `mremap()`. Hence, my idea in code would be:

```
buf = mmap(NULL, oldsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED);
buf = mremap(buf, oldsize, oldsize + 1, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
```

Would I end up with a null-terminated string?

Comment: Why don't you `mmap()` `oldsize+1` from the beginning?

Comment: @EOF, do you know if it is safe if I can guarantee not writing after `oldsize`?

Comment: I get a segfault when I try to read the added byte in a multiple-of-pagesz file and mremaping doesn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenter told above, you can add 1 already to the size when calling `mmap` and there's no need for `mremap()`.

It is not portable though.

On Linux it is quite safe to use as Linus Torvalds himself once described that trick in a forum post on the realworldtech website and I can not imagine that he will change that anytime soon, as it would break a lot of code (no link to the post, sorry, realworldtech's forum is not searchable and that post was done 6 or 7 years ago).

I know with certainty, that this trick doesn't work on Solaris Sparc since a 2010 version of `libc`. I know that because I got burned by that problem around that time when the library had been updated on our system. 
I had to bite the bullet and change all our code so that it never tried to touch outside the size of the file.
The Solaris man page tells with no uncertain words about that.

> The `mmap()` function allows `[pa, pa + len)` to  extend  beyond
>        the  end  of  the  object both at the time of the `mmap()` and
>        while the mapping persists, such as when the file is created
>        prior  to  the  `mmap()` call and has no contents, or when the
>        file is truncated. **Any reference to addresses beyond the end
>        of  the  object**,  however,  will result in the delivery of a
>        `SIGBUS` or `SIGSEGV` signal. The `mmap()` function cannot be used
>        to implicitly extend the length of files.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach doesn't work for me. The "added" byte causes a segfault.

What does work is when, for a file whose size is a multiple of the pagesize, I `mmap` `filesize`+`pagesize` bytes of anonymous memory then `mmap`
the file over it with `MAP_FIXED`.

Comment: This doesn't work either. You get a SIGBUS instead of a SIGSEGV.